# How to get file path of xlsx file in Android 11 from URI

Tags: android, android-11, scoped-storage

I am working on an application to read excel file (xlsx) file data. I was using custom file picker to select the file in android 10 and below, But in Andrid 11 it doesnt show the xlsx files.

So i made a change in my code for Android 11.

```
//to launch file picker
getContent.launch("*/*")

//to read selected file
val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
        readExcelData(uri!!.path!!)
}
```

the above code "uri!!.path!!" gives exception

```
/document/primary:Android/OldFileWithNewRecords.xlsxException:
E/ExcelActivity: FileNotFoundException/document/primary:Android/OldFileWithNewRecords.xlsx: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Is there any way i can get the exact path of the file selected?

I tried SimpleStorage and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70344438/6764161) but was not able to succeed.

Comment: "Is there any way i can get the exact path of the file selected?" -- no. First, the user might not have selected a file on the filesystem. Second, even if they did, you probably do not have access to that file on the filesystem.

Comment: For no file selected, i can apply the null check, but how can i get the file path in selected scenario?